# Duplicate Node object MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm a new starter to node and sql. I have a question:
I have 3 tables in MySQL
1- Day
2- Exercises
3- Sets

I used Join SQL statement to retrieve data from all 3 of the tables. The problem is, I have 1 day, 1 exercise but 3 sets of reps. so with my statement, I got 3 day object with the same dayID and exerciceID but with a single set of reps.

Any ideea how to combine everithing in a single object when i have a single dayID ?

This is a little app which let me store daily exercises..

---

This is the postman response

```
[
{
    "dayID": 11,
    "dayName": "monday",
    "exerciceID": 5,
    "exName": "Biceps Curl braces",
    "exComments": "close to body elbows",
    "setID": 3,
    "repNumbers": 12,
    "timeBetween": "3",
    "weights": 12,
    "comments": "Add another 2 reps"
},
{
    "dayID": 11,
    "dayName": "monday",
    "exerciceID": 5,
    "exName": "Biceps Curl braces",
    "exComments": "close to body elbows",
    "setID": 4,
    "repNumbers": 12,
    "timeBetween": "3",
    "weights": 12,
    "comments": "Add another 2 reps"
},
{
    "dayID": 11,
    "dayName": "monday",
    "exerciceID": 5,
    "exName": "Biceps Curl braces",
    "exComments": "close to body elbows",
    "setID": 5,
    "repNumbers": 12,
    "timeBetween": "3",
    "weights": 12,
    "comments": "Add another 2 reps"
}
```

]

---

this is the statement i used =
const sql = `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM workoutday w JOIN exercice e ON w.dayID = e.dayID JOIN sets s ON e.exerciceID = s.exerciceID`;

Thanks

Comment: So your queries is for listing reps of a single day or listing reps of a period of time grouping by 1 day?

Comment: yes.  My goal is to have a single day but when i call the endpoint, i should have what ever exercices and sets i complete

Answer (score 0):

you have to use INNER JOIN not only join.

if this dosen't work your query code in node is probably executed 3 times (this at last, 90% is the first option)

Comment: JOIN and INNER JOIN are functionally equivalent. INNER JOIN just a bit clearer to read